# Magick.NET-Q8 7.2 breaks and I can not catch the error

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I am using Magick.NET-Q8 AnyCPU 7.2, Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10
This is my code:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(imagedata))
{
    image.Quality = 60;
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpg;
    image.Composite(new MagickImage(watermarkFullPath), CompositeOperator.Over);

    //Save Big Image , This line works properly
    image.Write("somewhere\\myimage.jpg");

    //Save Smaller
    image.Resize(width, height);

    try
    {
        //this line breaks and nothing is done
        //program jumps over the whole function
        image.Write("somewhere\\mysmallimage.jpg");
    }
    catch
    {
        //the error never reaches here
    }
}
```

Why The program breaks without no error trace?
I also remark that this error appeared after I upgraded my development Windows
from 8.1 to 10

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

It appears new versions of Magick.NET-Q8 AnyCPU (7.0 or newer) can use GPU to process resizing images so you can force Magick.NET to use CPU only by following code:

```
ImageMagick.OpenCL.IsEnabled = false;
```

Put this line of code before resizinig command then Resize works as before.